# Facebook graph api post on group wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to make this call:

```
$result = $fb->api("/$g_id/feed", "POST", $args);
```

Where `$g_id` is the group page `id`

The call returns this error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 104
   }
}
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Do you have an accesstoken that allows you to post in the group? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/

Comment: Early I do it without accesstoken. Facebook change something in api?

Comment: _"Early I do it without accesstoken"_ No way! **You can't do any POST request without an active access_token**

Comment: Why eraly its work without errors?

Comment: And how I can get access_token?

Comment: The access token is the only way to prove author identity. So if you say you POST Status Update without access token, that's mean you're saying that “A Facebook post without author”, it's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the whole code which will help you to post to group's wall using graph API.

```
$accessToken    = $fb->getAccessToken();
$message            = 'Facebook graph api post on group wall';
$postData           = array ( 'access_token' => $accessToken,
                        'message' => $message,
                        );
        $response = $fb->api('/GROUPID/feed', "POST", $postData);
```

The response array will give you the post id.